# How to force a new app to be placed on the main home screen section (iPad 6)

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, sort

Specs: 2018 Ipad 6, latest iOS

When installing a new app, the app is sent to a new section of the home screen.

I prefer to have all my apps on a single home screen.

How do I force the app to be installed by default on the only section of the home screen instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Is it full?  To my understanding apps will only be placed on the front page if it has room to hold it.

Comment: There is plenty of room.

Comment: https://www.apple.com/feedback/  to register your concern about Apple's bad decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force that to happen.

However, you can move the app after installation. You do this by pressing and holding on the app icon on the home screen. After a few seconds, the icons will start "wiggling" - and you then press and hold to pick the icon up, and then move it to the place you want. If you hold the icon on the side of the screen, you will flip to the previous/next section of the home screen.

Comment: I already know how to do that. I cycle to new games very frequently so this is a BAD decision by Apple. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: I'm just the messenger.